# How can I remove elements in list in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have list in a list and I want to remove reoccurring element across the lists:

```
one = [['apple','pear','bear'],['apple','drawers','bear','grapes']]
```

I want to remove 'apple' from all of the lists within the list `one`. Simply put, my goal is to remove one element 'apple' from all of the nested lists.

```
new_one = [['pear','bear'],['drawers','bear','grapes']]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: why only `apple`, and why not `bear` as well? Any particular logic here..

Comment: Adding to mu's question: what if an element appears twice in the same list?

Comment: Do you know how to remove something from **one** of the lists? If so, just use a loop to repeat the action.

Comment: @mu無 No particular logic, I simply want to remove 'apple' , and it appears once

Answer (score 2):

```
newList = [[element for element in sublist if element != "apple"] for sublist in one]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
[ a, b ] = one
return [ [ x for x in a if x not in b ], [ x for x in b if x not in a ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
for(var x=0;x<one.length;x++) {
  one[x].splice(one[x].indexOf('apple'), 1);
}
```

Comment: um, I thought this was a python question

Answer (score 0):

```
one = [['apple','pear','bear'],['apple','drawers','bear','grapes']]
new_one = [element.remove('apple') for element in one]
# new_one = [['pear','bear'],['drawers','bear','grapes']]
```

This works if any given list inside the list of lists ONLY includes 'apple' one time. If it appears multiple times, it only removes the first 'apple'.

> I want to remove 'apple' from all of the lists within the list one. Simply put, my goal is to remove one element 'apple' from all of the nested lists.

```
one = [['apple','pear','bear'],['apple','drawers','bear','grapes', 'apple']]
new_one = [element.remove('apple') for element in one]
# new_one = [['pear','bear'],['drawers','bear','grapes', 'apple']]
```